# Multiple copies of .so and a.out file in the process address space

Tags: c, linux

I was seeing where the stack , heap and shared library's address ranges starts. I'm seeing 2 values for shared library(which i created) and a.out. 3 values for ld and libc. rest is anonymous and stack region starting addresses.

```
kg>pmap 24545
24545:   ./a.out

003d3000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
004d9000      4K r-x--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/libfile_sys.so
004da000      4K rwx--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/libfile_sys.so
08048000      4K r-x--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/a.out
08049000      4K rwx--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/a.out
46f46000    100K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
46f5f000      4K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
46f60000      4K rwx--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
46f68000   1244K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
4709f000      8K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
470a1000      4K rwx--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
470a2000     12K rwx--    [ anon ]
b7f8a000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
b7fa1000      4K rw-s-  /dev/zero (deleted)
b7fa2000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
bfc0f000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
```

Why is that we have 2 copies instead of one. Is the one is from the disk and the other one is currently in memory. What is the purpose of having the two copies of the same data in memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not multiple copies, they are just different segments with different permissions.  Look at the executable:

```
08048000      4K r-x--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/a.out
08049000      4K rwx--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/a.out
```

You can see that the first mapping has `r-x` permissions and the second mapping has `rwx` permissions.  Ordinarily, the second mapping would have `rw` permissions but maybe your processor isn't capable of setting no-execute permissions, or maybe the feature is turned off, maybe the program was compiled with an executable data segment, or maybe the processor doesn't have the required granularity.

I think i386 without PAE has very coarse granularity for the NX-bit, so that might explain why the data segments are executable but the stack isn't.

Comment: Also note that some of the "copies" don't have the same size, so they can't be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
46f46000    100K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so    
46f5f000      4K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
```

46f5f000 - 46f46000  = 25 * 4k = 100k. Its the last segment of the file. I still cant explain why but i found this.